# How solve "cannot index a value of type `usize`" error?

Tags: rust

I am trying to measure the speed of `Vec`'s `[]` indexing vs. `.get(index)`  using the following code:

```
extern crate time;

fn main() {
    let v = vec![1; 1_000_000];
    let before_rec1 = time::precise_time_ns();

    for (i, v) in (0..v.len()).enumerate() {
        v[i]
    }
    let after_rec1 = time::precise_time_ns();
    println!("Total time: {}", after_rec1 - before_rec1);


    let before_rec2 = time::precise_time_ns();

    for (i, v) in (0..v.len()).enumerate() {
        v.get(i)
    }
    let after_rec2 = time::precise_time_ns();
    println!("Total time: {}", after_rec2 - before_rec2);
}
```

but this returns the following errors:

```
error: cannot index a value of type `usize`
 --> src/main.rs:8:9
  |
8 |         v[i]
  |         ^^^^

error: no method named `get` found for type `usize` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:17:11
   |
17 |         v.get(i)
   |           ^^^
```

I'm confused why this doesn't work, since `enumerate` should give me an index which, by its very name, I should be able to use to index the vector.

1. Why is this error being thrown?
2. I know I can/should use iteration rather than C-style way of indexing, but for learning's sake what do I use to iterate over the index values like I'm trying to do here?

Comment: In `for (i, v)` the `v` is shadowing the previous definition of `v` which is the vector you're trying to index. Your entire loop could probably be optimised out though, since you aren't using the result of the indexing operation anywhere.

Comment: Please do not add **answers** to your **question**. I've rolled back to your original version and then applied some normal cleanup. You are welcome and encouraged to add your own answer if you believe you have something substantial to add to any existing answers. You can also add a comment to existing answers if you just want to provide a small amount of additional detail to an existing answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You, pal, are mightily confused here.

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1; 1_000_000];
```

This `v` has type `Vec<i32>`.

```
for (i, v) in (0..v.len()).enumerate() {
    v[i]
}
```

You are iterating over a range of indexes, from `0` to `v.len()`, and using `enumerate` to generate indices as you go:

- This `v` has type `usize`
- In the loop, `v == i`, always

So... indeed, the compiler is correct, you cannot use `[]` on `usize`.

---

The program "fixed":

```
extern crate time;

fn main() {
    let v = vec![1; 1_000_000];

    let before_rec1 = time::precise_time_ns();

    for i in 0..v.len() {
        v[i]
    }

    let after_rec1 = time::precise_time_ns();
    println!("Total time: {}", after_rec1 - before_rec1);


    let before_rec2 = time::precise_time_ns();

    for i in 0..v.len() {
        v.get(i)
    }

    let after_rec2 = time::precise_time_ns();
    println!("Total time: {}", after_rec2 - before_rec2);
}
```

I would add a disclaimer, though, that if I were a compiler, this useless loop would be optimized into a noop. If, after compiling with `--release`, your programs reports `0`, this is what happened.

Rust has built-in [benchmarking support](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/benchmark-tests.html), I advise that you use it rather than going the naive way. And... you will also need to inspect the assembly emitted, which is the only way to make sure that you are measuring what you think you are (optimizing compilers are tricky like that).